# Spring Integration : How to check whether the input xml is well-formed

Tags: xml, spring-integration, well-formed

I am using Spring Integration and was wondering how can I check whether the incoming xml request is well formed or not?  I am using  with schema , but I don't think it will check for well-formed xml.

Any ideas?

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us know that `<int-xml:validating-filter>` doesn't fit your requirements:

```
<int-xml:validating-filter id="filterA" 
                           schema-type="${xmlSchema}"
                           input-channel="inputChannelA"
                           output-channel="validOutputChannel"
                           discard-channel="invalidOutputChannel"
                           schema-location="org/springframework/integration/xml/config/validationTestsSchema.xsd"/>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/xml.html#xml-validating-filter

Comment: Hi, I know that this is an old post. but does this filter come in a java config version.
I can't find any mention of it in internet. Thanks

Comment: The `MessageFilter` is a `MessageHandler` implementation to use in the Java config, e.g. with with the `@ServiceActivator` or in `.handle()` of Java DSL. This one must be supplied with the `XmlValidatingMessageSelector`. Although you may consider to use a `@Bean` annotation combination with the `@Filter` on that `XmlValidatingMessageSelector`. The last one can be used in the Java DSL's `.filter(GenericSelector<P>)` definition.